Running a trading algorithm- On-premise vs Cloud
I am seeking insights from traders who have implemented algorithmic trading programs on the cloud or at their local workstations. My goal is to determine the most efficient, cost-effective, and scalable option that meets my performance and security requirements.
Project Overview:
I am looking to implement a medium frequency trading system that trades in capital markets. My initial setup executes orders per 10 seconds, but I will upscale it to 1 millisecond in due course. I have reservations about the scalability of my local machine to handle varying loads. Also, I came across multiple resources that suggest cloud solutions are more reliable. I am also skeptical about redundancy and failover mechanisms on the cloud. Is my data secure?
Given my strategy executes orders in a time-sensitive interval, latency and bandwidth are my utmost priority. Also, cloud solutions are managed services so I can better focus on monitoring the system, rather than doing maintenance. Any suggestions about system configurations and networking protocols are most welcome.
Thank you for your time and effort in responding to this question. I am grateful for your insights.
Thanks,
Sandeep

If I were to answer all these qiestions I would charge steep consulting fees :) In fact it sounds like questions one would ask a consultant. Not sure this is the place for that.

I’m voting to close this question.

@Frido Hello. I am not looking for any professional consultation. I just want to know the experiences of people who have implemented trading programs on the cloud or at home. Maybe I shouldn't have included the cost factor.

I think you'll probably have more success getting answers if you narrow down your question. As it is your question is too general. And indeed costs is not sth that will be discussed here anyways. My 2 cents.

Thanks for the review. On it!

Also, as this is a quantitative finance space, questions that require a quantitative answer (as opposed to qualitative) are preferred.



What are the key features and benefits of on-premises and cloud solutions for trading algorithms?


Here is some perspective from a QuantRocket blog article on this topic:

The cloud is more expensive and less powerful than your local workstation
The cloud provides an isolated environment, but so can Docker
The cloud is more reliable than your home office
Use a different machine for research and live trading

See the full article: Cloud or Local: Where to Run Your Quant Trading?
